# Dropping wi-fi calls from one access point to another

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I have a long house, and must use two wireless access points to get full coverage. I also have terrible cell coverage so I often use wi-fi calling on my android phone to accommodate. However, when I walk from one side of the house to the other, the call often get muddled or even drops as I pass from what I believe is one zone of coverage into the other. Both of these access point are set for access point behavior only and go back to a home router and then out through our U-verse gigabyte connection. Signal strength throughout the house seems very strong. For home access points or on phones, is there some setting I need to throw to ensure the hand-off between access points happens seamlessly? I know there are some solutions out there that handle this, but I don't have the $$ to buy an enterprise class setup ... any direction is much appreciated.